# Is this correct integration for $\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I've been searching the internet and I can't find out if this is the correct integration of $\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm  dx$. I did this using a similar method to what I found for the integration of $\int\frac{1}{\cos(x)} \,\mathrm dx$.

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm dx =\frac{\ln\left|\dfrac{\cos(x)+1}{\cos(x)-1}\right|}{2} $$

Comment: Adding your work would be helpful in determining *where* you went wrong if you did make a mistake. Regardless, it seems like you're missing a factor of a negative sign somewhere.$$\int\csc x\,\mathrm dx=\frac 12\log\left(\frac {\cos x\color{red}{-}1}{\cos x\color{red}{+}1}\right)+C$$I suspect it has something to do with how you expanded out the fraction after substitution. You can also double check by just differentiating the RHS and seeing if you get $\csc x$.

Comment: Are you sure? After checking my negatives seems right. Someone in the answers seems to agree with me. However if you still have doubts I can upload my working later.

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. I for some reason thought $\cos^2 x-1$ was $\sin^2 x$, oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\int \frac{1}{\cos x} d x$, we first multiply both numerator and denominator by $\cos x$

$$
\int \frac{1}{\cos x} d x=\int \frac{\cos x}{\cos ^2 x} d x
$$

and let $u=\sin x$, then $du=\cos xdx$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\cos x} d x & =\int \frac{d u}{1-u^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int\left(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u}\right) d u \\
& =\frac{1}{2}(-\ln |1-u|+\ln |1+u|)+C \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right|+C \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sin x+1}{\sin x-1}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry I have no clue what is going on here

Comment: Your answer for the first integral is wrong.  It should be $\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\cos x-1}{\cos x+1}\right|$.  I now share with you the solution of the second integral and wish it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another alternative for a given integral:
$\begin{aligned}\int\dfrac{1}{\sin x}\, \mathrm dx & = \int \csc x \, \mathrm dx =\\
& =\int \csc x \dfrac{\csc x +\cot x}{\csc x +\cot x}\, \mathrm dx=\\
& =\int\dfrac{\csc^2x+\csc x \cot x}{\csc x +\cot x}\,\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}u=\csc x + \cot x,\\ \mathrm du = -\csc x(\cot x +\csc x)\mathrm dx\end{cases}=\\
& = \int\dfrac{-\mathrm du}{u}=-\ln|u|+C=\boxed{-\ln|\csc x + \cot x|+C}.\end{aligned}$